# site_url changes localhost to [::1]

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've used CodeIgniter before and it's been quite a long time since I've last used it so I'm basically going back to step 1.

I have the controller CaseCon with the following codes

```
  public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('CaseView');
    }

  public function sendTicket() {
    echo "This is sendTicket function";
  }
```

and my html page has the following code

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo site_url('CaseCon/sendTicket');?>">
  <input id="full_name" type="text" class="validate" name="Name" value="Name" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I'm trying to run this on a local server. Upon clicking the submit button, the page reloads and changes the `localhost:8888` to `[::1]`. I'm not sure which part do I have an error. I'm getting the expected output if I force the url to go to `/index.php/CaseCon/sendTicket`.

Kindly advise. Thanks.

Comment: instead localhost:8888 you get localhost:1 or [::1] ?

Comment: are you loading $this->load->helper('url'); ? what do you have in the configuration file?

Comment: I'm loading it along with the index function (not included in top code).  It looks like this currently `public function index()
    { $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->view('CaseView');
    }`. I did move it to the autoload though so the autoload has this code now `$autoload['helper'] = array('url');`

Comment: Chk your virtual host .

Comment: Woaah. I'm currently using MAMP. What I did was click 'Set Web & MySQL ports to 80 & 3306'. I loaded `localhost` instead of `localhost:8888` since I change the port. I tried clicking the submit button. Although it now shows the right output, the `localhost` is still being replaced with `[::1]`. Since I achieved what I want, I guess I'll try to figure out something when I encounter problems. Thanks!

Comment: @Jeremy did u try try my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would think You have your base_url blank.

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

That is why `[::1]` You don't have set your base_url but that is what will happen

Set your base url

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/your_project_name/';
```

Or

```
$config['config_base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8888/your_project_name/';
```

> Note: Your class and file name only have first letter upper case.

File name: Casecon.php

```
class Casecon extends CI_Controller {

  public function index() {

  }
}
```

It might work on localhost the way you have it but on some live servers you will run into issue.

View form

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url('casecon/sendTicket');?>">
  <input id="full_name" type="text" class="validate" name="Name" value="Name" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

How to create a [Controller](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#let-s-try-it-hello-world)

How to create a [Model](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#anatomy-of-a-model)