# Getting redirected to http://[::1]/dashboard/ on submitting form

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, xampp

Today out of the blue I have started getting redirected to http://[::1]/dashboard/ on my website in localhost when I click to submit a form. I have no idea whats going on. It was working fine just a few hours ago and I have changed nothing in the code.

This is the form's opening and closing tags:

```
<form action="<?= site_url('Buyer_Controller/view_cart') ?>" method= "post">

<input type="image" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/a2c.jpg');?>"  />
```

Comment: why written  <?php tag between html?

Comment: You need to set your base url. If your using CI3 and above

Comment: I've edited it out. It was about something else. The focus is on the opening and closing tags.

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34025305/ip-address-is-showing-in-form-action-with-codeigniter-http-1-codeigniter-in/34031347#34031347

Comment: I have set the base URL as `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/my_project_name/';`
but now getting redirected to http://localhost/dashboard/. Interestingly enough, I just noticed that if I don't do any changes to the form values (check check-boxes etc.) then I get to next page without a hitch. :(

Comment: Checkout the page view source to verify the base_url .

Comment: Ali, page view source has the correct path i.e `<form action="http://localhost/myproject/index.php?/Buyer_controller/view_cart" method= "post">` but it still goes to http://localhost/dashboard/. :(

Answer (score 1):

If you are redirected to the XAMPP dashboard, do the following:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourproject/';
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.example.com/';
```

Answer (score 0):

Have set ur base_url properly?

For reference, see this post:
[site_url changes localhost to [::1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35349416/site-url-changes-localhost-to-1)

You can set one global config variable.

Comment: I have set the base URL as `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/my_project_name/';` but now getting redirected to `http://localhost/dashboard/`. Interestingly enough, I just noticed that if I don't do any changes to the form values (check check-boxes etc.) then I get to desired page.

Comment: U can try like this <? echo $config['base_url']."Buyer_Controller/view_cart" ; ?>